# html tag removing function does not whole file

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql function that strips html tags out of a dumb file, however it doens't do the whole file. This is my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CLearHTMLTags(@htmlInput VARCHAR(MAX),@newChar char(1))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @begin BIGINT
DECLARE @end BIGINT
DECLARE @length BIGINT
SET @begin = CHARINDEX('<', @htmlInput)
SET @end = CHARINDEX('>', @htmlInput, CHARINDEX('<',@htmlInput))
SET @length = (@end - @begin) + 1 WHILE @begin > 0 AND @end > 0 AND @length > 0
BEGIN 
IF (UPPER(SUBSTRING(@htmlInput, @begin, 4)) <> '') AND (UPPER(SUBSTRING(@htmlInput, @begin, 5))<>'')
BEGIN
SET @htmlInput = RTRIM(LTRIM(STUFF(@htmlInput,@begin,@length,@newChar)))
END
ELSE SET @length = 0;
SET @begin = CHARINDEX('<', @htmlInput, @end-@length)
SET @end = CHARINDEX('>', @htmlInput, CHARINDEX('<', @htmlInput,@begin))
SET @length = (@end - @begin)+1
END
RETURN isnull(RTRIM(LTRIM(@htmlInput)),'')
END
```

If I run dus through the file it will do the first 20 lines or something and than it stops. 
My file that i tested with is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>EenmaalAndermaal</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body id="content">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Site name and toggle button -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="./">EenmaalAndermaal</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="./">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="browse.html">Openstaande veilingen</a></li>
            <li><a href="overOns.html">Over ons</a></li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="register.html">Registeren</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                Inloggen <span class="caret"></span>
              </a>

              <div class="dropdown-menu" id="formLogin">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                    <form class="">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="login_username">Gebruikersnaam</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="username" id="login_username" type="text">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="login_password">Wachtwoord</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="password" id="login_password" type="password">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in pull-left"></span>
                          Inloggen
                        </button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="text-center">
                        <a href="wachtwoordvergeten.html">Wachtwoord Vergeten</a>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Zoeken">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Zoeken</span>
                    </button>
                  </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="page-header">Goede staat tweedehands fiets</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
              <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://www.studentfiets.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/damesfiets-04.jpg" height="200">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
              <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://www.studentfiets.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/STU-fietsnieuw-04.jpg" height="200">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
              <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://www.studentfiets.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/herenfiets-03.jpg" height="200">
            </div>
          </div>

          <hr>

          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h1 class="panel-title">Details</h1>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <tr>
                <td>Verkoper:</td>
                <td><a href="">Max Molewijk</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Beschrijving:</td>
                <td>Deze mooie fiets is goed te gebruiken voor tripjes naar het station. Het bevat 3 versnellingen en een bagagedrager. Voor in de nacht is het uitgerust met een koplamp en een dynamo. Een interresante feature van deze prachtige fiets is dat de remmen je af en toe kunnen verrassen. Er is ook geen sleutel nodig om deze fiets van het slot te halen. Het is een bijna nieuwe staat met maar 1.000 km op de teller.</td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Startprijs:</td>
                <td>€ 70,-</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Betalingswijze:</td>
                <td>Bank/Giro</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Betalingsinstructies:</td>
                <td>Overschrijving moet ontvangen zijn binnen 3 dagen</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Voorwerplocatie</td>
                <td>Arnhem, Nederland</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Looptijd</td>
                <td>14 dagen</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Verzendkosten:</td>
                <td>€ 14,99</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Verzendinstructies:</td>
                <td>Kom ophalen bij Neppestraat 90 Arnhem</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Voorwerpnummer:</td>
                <td>336035</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="panel panel-primary bids">
            <div class="panel-body bids-header bg-primary text-center">
              <div class="price">€ 105,-</div>
              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span>
                    </span>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" value="110">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
              <div class="time">11:41:38</div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-striped text-center">
              <tr>
                <th class="text-center col-xs-4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></th>
                <th class="text-center col-xs-4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span></th>
                <th class="text-center col-xs-4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Mattijn</td>
                <td><b>€ 105,-</b></td>
                <td><span class="label label-default">10:09 8-5-17</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Joost</td>
                <td><b>€ 95,-</b></td>
                <td><span class="label label-default">13:47 7-5-17</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Toine</td>
                <td><b>€ 80,01</b></td>
                <td><span class="label label-default">17:24 6-5-17</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Bas</td>
                <td><b>€ 80,-</b></td>
                <td><span class="label label-default">22:35 5-5-17</span></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Anyone an idea how to fix this?
Much thanks in regards

Comment: any reason why you are not treating the xml with the xml datatype in sql server? That way you can use xquery and other xml-type functions directly instead of text parsing.

Comment: What are the input to your SP and what is the output that you get? Please give the exact input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look out for using charindex and substring and other string methods on varchar(max) and nvarchar(max). There is some limitations on how many characters they can actually traverse and the datatypes they return.

My advice would be that you experiment with xquery and .nodes() to get a dataset of the type you are after in your solution.

Comment: The fix is easy I found out. The output of sql server to console is limited. It actually does the whole file but doesn't show it when you want to try it out in the console.